# Problems with abstract data type code in C

Tags: c

I have this types defined:

```
#define NAME_LENGTH_LIMIT 25
#define LNULL (-1)
#define MAX 1000

typedef char tParticipantName[NAME_LENGTH_LIMIT];
typedef int tNumVotes;
typedef bool tEUParticipant;

typedef struct tItemL {
    tParticipantName participantName;
    tNumVotes numVotes;
    tEUParticipant EUParticipant;
} tItemL;
typedef int tPosL;
typedef struct tList {
    tItemL data[MAX];
    tPosL lastPos;
} tList;
```

This code below is creating problems, because it needs to read a character but when I insert one I recived this error-> error: invalid operands to binary == (have 'tItemL' and 'tItemL').

```
tPosL findItem(tItemL d, tList L) {
    tPosL t;
    if (L.lastPos == LNULL) {
        return LNULL;
    } else {
        t = first(L); //p=0;
        while (t != LNULL && (L.data[t] == d)) { //error in this line
            t = next(t, L);
        }
        if (L.data[t] == d) return t;//error in this line 
        else return LNULL;
    }
}
```

I don't know how to solve the problem

Comment: You cannot do this I guess `(L.data[t] == d)`. You are trying to compare two structs.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (L.data[t] == d)
```

Here `L.data[t]` and `d` evaluates to `struct`s.

You can't compare two `struct`s for equality with the `==` operator.

You need to compare each member separately.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should pass the pointer to this big struct, not the struct itself as every time you **copy** the whole thing when you call the function.
2. Do hide standard types behind typedefs.
3. Do not hide arrays behind typedefs

```
typedef struct tItemL {
    char participantName[NAME_LENGTH_LIMIT];
    int numVotes;
    bool EUParticipant;
} tItemL;

typedef int tPosL;
typedef struct tList {
    tItemL data[MAX];
    tPosL lastPos;
} tList;

int compare(const tItemL *i1, const tItemL *i2)
{
    return strcmp(i1 -> participantName, i2 -> participantName) &&
           i1 -> numVotes == i2 -> numVotes &&
           i1 -> EUParticipant && i1 -> EUParticipant;
}

int findItem(tItemL *d, tList *L) {
    int t = -1;
    if (L -> lastPos == LNULL) {
        return LNULL;
    } else {
        t = first(L); //p=0;
        while (t != LNULL && compare(&L -> data[t], d)) { //error in this line
            t = next(t, L);
        }
        if (compare(&L -> data[t], d)) return t;//error in this line 
        else return LNULL;
    }
}
```

You need to change other functions to take pointers not `struct`